# IdentityServer4 and Tableau Server OpenID authorization

Tags: openid, identity-management, tableau-api

I'm attempting to get authorization working with IdentityServer4 from Tableau server with OpenID and I'm not having any luck. I have a IdentityServer4 client configured for the supported OpenID Authorization Code Flow and I am able to get through the first few steps of redirect to IdentityServer login page, login successfully, accept claim types and then when redirected back to Tableau I get a `User could not be found` error. I'm using the in memory test user (bob) that comes with IdentityServer install and have created that exact user and email address in Tableau.

My client is as follows:

```
new Client
   {
       ClientId = "tableau",
       ClientSecrets =
       {                       
           new Secret("[my secret]", "tableau.secret")
           {
               Type = SecretTypes.SharedSecret
           },                       
       },

       AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials,
       AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
       AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
       RedirectUris = { "http://[tableuServer]/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/openIdLogin" },
       AllowOfflineAccess = true,

       AllowedScopes =
       {
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Phone,
           IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Address
       }
   },
```

I'm really hoping someone has already got this working, and can share a working client or a change I need to make. This IdentityServer is working for 3 other client types, so I know I'm good in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Tableau unable to identify the user.  Verify any mismatch between username in Tableau and Identity Server.  The Identity Server sends unique user identifier ( The **sub** claim in IDToken) in IDToken.  This sub claim in IDToken is used to identify the user in Tableau. 
Few reference links: 
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/openid_auth_troubleshooting.htm
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/openid_auth_signing_in.htm